# Changing a get request to a post in python?

Tags: python, forms, post, get

I have this-

> en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=login&lgname=user&lgpassword=password

But it doesn't work because it is a get request.  What would the the post request version of this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The variables for a POST request are in the HTTP headers, not in the URL.
Check [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).

edit:
Try this (i got it from [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
values = {'action' : 'login',
          'lgname' : 'user',
          'password' : 'password' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'action' : 'login', 'lgname' : 'user', 'lgpassword' : 'password'})
response = urllib.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", params)
```

info about urllib can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample is in PHP, use $_REQUEST, this holds the contents of both $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: the sample is a URL, it's not in any language.